# How to get TinyMCE displayed on a jsfpage?

Tags: javascript, jsf, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am new to jsf and I want to use TinyMCE as a rich text editor on my web page. I followed the installation instruction given by TinyMCE here:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22

I am using netbean as my IDE. I put the tiny_mce folder under a folder named "resources" which is put under "Web-Pages" folder located directly under the -WAR project folder,

I have this in my newjsf.xhtml  page

```
<h:head>     
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="/resources/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "simple"          
        });
    </script>     

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="window">          

        <h:inputTextarea id="field" value="#{test.text}"  />

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

here is the managedbean.

```
public class test {

private String text;

public test() {
}

/**
 * @return the text
 */
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

/**
 * @param text the text to set
 */
public void setText(String text) {
    System.out.println("setted me!!!!!!!!!" + text);
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

What I get on the browser page is just a plain textarea 
"" 
instead of a tinyMCE text editor. Isn't it true that the javascript will automatically replace the plain textarea with the TinyMCE? or did I specify the path of tiny_mce.js wrongly such that the program cannot find source of the .js file be loaded? Weird thing is my glassfish server log has no error/ exception output when I open the newjsf.xhtml page. just the TinyMCE is a plain textarea instead of what's shown in the demo.

Thank you!

---

I solve the display problem. It was indeed caused by the place where I put the tiny_mce folder. I try to mimic the example web pages in the package and put the .js file to a path that has the relative structure as the example and the editor is displayed. The new problem I encountered is the how to pass the inputTextarea content to managerbean. I have the two lines below to submit the content.

h:inputTextarea  value="#{test.text}" 
p:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{test.print}"

methods my managerbean

```
public void print (){
    if (this.text == null) {
        System.out.println("why");
    } else {
        System.out.println(this.text + "i got it");
    }
}   
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
    System.out.println("setted me!!!!!!!!!" + text);
    this.text = text;
}
```

when I submit, the server output is this.

INFO: setted me!!!!!!!!!
INFO: i got it

All content I typed in is not captured even the call to setter is fired. Could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: info: tinymce hides the textarea and inserts a contenteditable iframe in the page

Answer (score 0):

I get it! just adding the onclick="tinyMCE.getContent()"   the content will be able to pass into managerbean. If you have any better suggestion, please post below.

Comment: You seem to be using PrimeFaces already. Why don't you just use its `<p:editor>`?